# Why does networkx reduce number of nodes after adding edges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, graph, networkx

I need to start this by saying that my code runs without any error messages, but I don't understand some of the results.

I create a graph in networkx from a pandas data frame, that has 398595 integer IDs.

```
# Create Graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.name = "Graph from Pandas"

# Add Nodes to Graph
G.add_nodes_from(test_df['ID'].tolist())
print(nx.info(G))
```

The output from nx.info(G) is as follows, which is also correct this is what I expected:

```
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 398595
Number of edges: 0
Average degree:   0.0000
```

Then I load a second pandas data frame and it contains 5556353 entries and has three columns:

```
ID1    ID2    weight
3      198    0.601002
3      183    0.618057
```

Each ID in ID1 or ID2 exists also into the first pandas dataframe, so I load the edges as follows:

```
# Add data to Graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='ID1',target='ID2', edge_attr='weight')
print(nx.info(G))
```

However here is what I don't understand, the output from nx.info(G) now returns:

```
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 29348
Number of edges: 4371353
Average degree: 297.8978
```

Now my questions are (1) why are there fewer nodes in this graph than before and (2) why are there considerably fewer edges in this Graph than available from the data frame?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are probably less unique IDs between ID1 and ID2 of df than there are in the ID column of test_df. The first thing I would check is if the unique IDs across ID1 and ID2 in df equals the number of nodes you display `len(pd.unique(df[['ID1','ID2']].values.ravel()))` (should equal 29348).
2. One reason there are fewer edges is if there are directed edges in the dataframe. The default value for the create_using parameter of `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` is `nx.Graph()` so edges will be treated as undirected and multiple edges are removed. If you want directed edges, multiple edges, or both, try passing nx.DiGraph,nx.MultiGraph, or nx.MultiDiGraph respectively to the `create_using` parameter.